# Using Python, is there a way to create a new tab and navigate to a site in an active Chrome browser?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I know I can use Selenium, but that opens a new browser window which isn't what I want. I would like to access the browser window I am already using and open a new tab with the domain/url I'm trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

This will open a new tab in default browser.

My Apologies, i dont have enough reputation to comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following code in my computer and opened a new tab in my default browser (Chrome in my case):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new('http://www.google.com')
```

If you want to open a new tab in a non-default browser you will have to do the following:

```
import webbrowser
b = webbrowser.get('Safari') # Or the path to the browser you want to use
b.open_new('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. The only other question I have is, can I pass cookies to the webbrowser? For instance, will this allow me to login to a Wordpress Website and then open the authenticated session in my current browser?

Comment: webbrowser can't handle cookies. You can try using Selenium, here there is an explanation of how to open a new tab with it http://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903